# How to reduce the time of connecting laptop to Wi-Fi in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, networkmanager, systemd-networkd

I use a new laptop model with AMD processor, Arch Linux and kernel 5.2.21 (this kernel version makes my laptop the least hot). When I try to disable Wi-Fi in the GNOME 3 settings and then connect again, it takes about 14 seconds to connect to the Wi-Fi router. For comparison, my Android 10 tablet takes about 4 seconds to connect to the same Wi-Fi router.
Maybe the reason is that I haven't installed or configured something on Arch?

Comment: This sounds more like an issue with a router or RF interference, i.e. you have too many routers competing for the same frequency. In the latter case switching to a 5GHz channel should help but all your devices must support it.

Comment: I only use the 5 GHz frequency on all my devices. The 2.4 GHz frequency is disabled on the router.

Comment: Try using a different WiFi router.